# Receive Payload from IBM MQ spring boot listner then send data to rabbit mq in functional approch

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

```
//take message from ibm mq    
@JmsListener(destination = "${ibm.mq.ackqueue}", concurrency="${ibm.mq.concurrency}")
public void receive(Message message){//get playload}

@Bean
public Function<Response, EventDto> transformEvent() {
//take response from ibm mq
//then process and send eventdto to rabbit mq from spring cloud stream approach
}
```

this two methods are need functional approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're receiving message from arbitrary resource (JMS in this case) and you want to use s-c-stream to send such message to RabbitMQ, you can use a component that is specifically designed for that case - `StreamBridge`

Simply autowire it and use it inside of the receive method to send a Message to Rabbit (providing rabbit binder is on the classpath)

You don't need

```
@Bean
public Function<Response, EventDto> transformEvent() {
//take response from ibm mq
//then process and send eventdto to rabbit mq from spring cloud stream approach
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources)